# Python unable to acquire Oracle environment handle in Apache

Tags: python, windows, oracle10g

I can run my django application using the developer server, but it does not run under apache.
 The error is:

> Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

Adding an ORACLE_HOME environment variable pointing to my 10g client did not fix the issue.

NOTE: the ORACLE_HOME did not end with a slash. Also, this is using the XAMPP version of Apache if that makes a difference.

Apache, Python, Django, and Oracle are all installed on the C: of a Windows 2003 32bit server. (No spaces in the name).

Final NOTE: The issue is in the use of XAMPP for the Apache server. When I installed the normal Apache, the issue did not appear. XAMPP must be modifying the path so that it cannot see the Oracle home.

Comment: does your ORACLE_HOME variable end with a slash `/` ?

Answer (score 0):

What is path to where your django application resides?

If it's in *c:\Program Files (x86)\XXX* (as seen on 64-bit Windows), this is a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555568)